# Passing current username and password from ReportViewer

Tags: reportviewer2008

I created a class to connect to SSRS using credentials

```
public class ReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
```

To implement it, I use:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials("username", "password", "domain");
```

The problem is that in this case I need to set these credentials, and I am using my username and password, which is not a good idea.
I want to connect using current userloggedin credentials or even make the ssrs think that the "everyone" is connecting to it, because I am not actually using credentials for producing reports, I just need to get connected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx) instead

That will use the default credentials of the person running the report instead of yours.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to implement it? I tried to use DefaultCredentials, unsuccessfully. Thanks

Comment: Here is an example: `ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;`